# Equilibrium Graphs

Tags: homework, thermodynamics, equilibrium, concentration

[image]

What if I2 and H2 began at the same concentration - then do we start at the same point? ... or is it acceptable to start at different concentrations...

Comment: The question probably won't start H2 and I2 at the same C so that it is easier to see the two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if I2 and H2 began at the same concentration - then do we start at the same point?

Yes (and in textbook problems involving graphs this situation would be avoided for the reason pointed out in brinnb's comment)

> is it acceptable to start at different concentrations...

Also yes.  No law against it.

I'm guessing that the graphs are part of a textbook problem. Are you able to figure out which graph can occur?